# Type narrowing: checking variable object key existence when noUncheckedIndexedAccess is true

Tags: typescript, strictnullchecks

I have `"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true` in my `tsconfig.json`. The whole point of the switch is to force the check of existence of the item at an index before accessing it.

*I struggle to do the check for object with a variable key:*

Say I have the following structure:

```js
const items: Record<string, {name: string}> = {
  '123': {
    name: 'asdf'
  }
}
```

when I try to check the existence using a literal key, the type narrowing works ok:

```js
if (items['123']) {
  // OK: Compiles no problem
  console.log(items['123'].name)
}
```

If I try to check the existence using a variable key, the compiler starts to complain.

```js
const id = '123';
if (items[id]) {
  // ERROR: items[id] - Object possibly undefined
  console.log(items[id].name)
}
```

*Why is it not possible to check the existence that way?*

I tried even different checks:

```js
if (id in items) {}
if (items.hasOwnProperty(id)) {}
if (typeof items[id] !== 'undefined') {}
```

no luck there.

The only thing that worked was

```js
const id = '123';
const item = items[id];
if (item) {
  // OK
  console.log(item.name)
}
```

I find it a bit too chatty, though.

▶️ [Examples above in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwgLhgJUaATgEwB5pc4wBzAGhgG8wBDZRDEs8gXwD4YBeWgKBhCYAcgCMAJgDMIjDUHDFDJhhH0I+AGYiFQ9v3384mmAAoEKCAG1x0kQF0AlAMUB6VzADyAaQwBhEGQABzgAG0QIGDAQGCDcEAAjcORdGFBIEHCAOlCQcnMkVBtJGXss5URHA35+dOh4fF5REpEAbiMTAssrOHwnFxh3GABRTExPTAwLIt77GABaLwSAKxxYIJAICDgkgE8YAFcwfERNMkR8BTrMxBy8rpm+8sZK6trweumm6etZ9uMzNNnPI3B4fKlrtlcvlps8mFV9EIgA)

**Environment:** TypeScript v4.5.4

Comment: On my end the code snippet you got an error on works (no TS error). However, it would throw an error if `id` was a parameter from a function, and the indexed lookup(`item[id]`) happened inside the function. Here is a phenomenal explanation of why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78083009/how-come-typescript-does-not-narrow-this-index-signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an issue on GitHub that's essentially describing this exact situation:

> [Can't narrow T | undefined into T with a falsy check when using --noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45570)

That issue is closed as a duplicate of this issue, which is still open as of February 2022:

> [Discriminant property type guard not applied with bracket notation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530)

Based on the discussion on that second issue and other linked issues, it sounds like this is a known limitation due to the performance overhead that would be required to implement this in the type checker, e.g. [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483#issuecomment-257436774):

> Declined due to performance reasons. Since it should almost always be possible to write `const j = list[i]` instead, this shouldn't be too burdensome.

Given that the issue is still open, it seems possible that this may be re-addressed at some point to support the behavior that you expect.