# How come TypeScript does not narrow this index signature?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this index signature type with a union as the value:

```
type Foo = { [key: string]: number | { [key: string]: number } }[];
```

If we try to narrow it:

```
const foo = (arr: Foo, outer: string, inner: string) => {
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    if(typeof element[outer] === 'number') {
      // element[outer] is a number
    }
    else if(!element[outer]) {
      // element[outer] is falsy (e.g. undefined)
    }
    else {
      // Here, TS should know that element[outer] is a well defined object
      console.log(element[outer]?.[inner]);
    }
  });
};
```

We get the following error message on `element[outer]?.[inner]`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'number | { [key: string]:
> number; }'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on
> type 'number | { [key: string]: number; }'.ts(7053)

Here is a similar example [from the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html), where narrowing works:

```
function padLeft(padding: number | string, input: string): string {
  if (typeof padding === "number") {
    return " ".repeat(padding) + input;
  }
  return padding + input;
}
```

How come the narrowing does not work in the first snippet above?

---

**EDIT:**

One solution is to assign the element to another variable. I do not understand why that works, or why it is necessary. In the docs example above, we did not have to re-assign the function parameter that we narrowed.

Works:

```
const foo2 = (arr: Foo, outer: string, inner: string) => {
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    const outerValue = element[outer]; // The key!
    if(typeof outerValue === 'number') {
      // element[outer] is a number
    }
    else if(!outerValue) {
      // element[outer] is falsy (e.g. undefined)
    }
    else {
      // Here, TS should know that element[outer] is a well defined object
      console.log(outerValue[inner]);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to save the value in a variable and do the type checks on that variable:

```
const foo = (arr: Foo, outer: string, inner: string) => {
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    const value = element[outer]

    if(typeof value === 'number') {
      // value is a number
    }
    else if(!value) {
      // value is falsy (e.g. undefined)
    }
    else {
      console.log(value[inner]); // This is now a { [key: string]: number }
    }
  });
};
```

The issue is that TS actually cannot narrow this the way you think because type narrowing only works on a static reference. In your case, you're constantly dynamically accessing the property of your object so there's no way for TS to make sure that the *same* property is being accessed consistently. This is why saving the value in a separate variable and doing the type checks works.

---

Now for the error that you get:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'number | { [key: string]: number; }'.

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'number | { [key: string]: number; }'.ts(7053)
```

Let's think about it this way:

- `element[outer]` is in fact a `number | { [key: string]: number }`, meaning it can either be number or an object.
- This means that if you wanted to manipulate `element[outer]` you would have to do it by taking into consideration an interface that can be compatible with both `number` and `{ [key: string]: number }` types, they probably don't share many things in common, but one thing they both have is a `toString()` method which means you could technically do a `element[outer].toString()` without any issues.
- Now, given that precedent, if you tried to access a dynamic property on `element[outer]` it would have to be one that can is present in both `number` and `{ [key: string]: number }`. Sadly, `number` does not have any way of accessing dynamic properties with a subscript operator (`[]`) which means that this type union does not have a guarantee that `element[outer][string]` exists, which is why it implicitly assumes the `any` type since it could very well exist if the precondition that `element[outer]` is really an object and not a number.

---

TL;DR: `element[outer]` is a union type between `number` and `{ [key: string]: number }` and `number` has no definition to access dynamic properties through the subscript operator (`[]`), you get this because you need to manipulate this union type in a way that is compliant with the interfaces of **both** types.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Could you please help me understand the error message? `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'number | { [key: string]: number; }'.ts(7053)` What exactly is that telling us? Is it saying that `element[outer]` is of type `number | { [key: string]: number; }`? I mean, the error message seems like a lie. The second part of the union is an `index signature with a parameter (key) of type 'string'`

Comment: Also, on the same note, instead of all those if statements I tried to do this: `const value = element[outer]; if(!value?.[inner]) return; console.log(value[inner]);`, but that did not work. Same odd error message. Any idea why?

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation (hope it helps). As for your second comment, the principle is the same. By doing `!value?.[inner]` you're trying to access `[inner]` on a number type which does not have a subscript operator defined. In JS this would normally return `undefined` which is valid but in TS this represents a compilation error because you're trying to access something that does not exist in the `Number` interface by definition.

Comment: A million thanks, very detailed and clear!